# How to update data in specific form field in UpdateView Django

Tags: django

Since I'm new in Django how can I update specific form field in django? when I do `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template it works, but there are some form field('s) thats not needed to show on the other form but some it requires. so what I did is that call them only the required fill to be updated on some forms.

here is my UpdateView:

```
class SettingsProfileView(UpdateView):
    model               = UserInfoModel
    template_name       = 'site/views/settingsprofile.html'
    form_class          = UserInfoForm
    success_url         = '/'

    def get_object(self, queryset = None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, users_id = self.kwargs['pk'])
```

This class generic view actually working on the `{{ form.as_p }}`
But there are some form fields that i dont want to be shown on that form.

for those who wants to see my html templates:
here it is ->

```
{% extends 'roots/site.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="card col-lg-12">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title"><h3>Personal Information Settings</h3></div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.firstname.label_tag }}
                {{ form.firstname }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.lastname.label_tag }}
                {{ form.lastname }}
            </div>
            <h4>Birthdate: </h4>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.birthdate_month.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.birthdate_day.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.birthdate_year.label_tag }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.birthdate_month }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.birthdate_day }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form.birthdate_year }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.gender.label_tag }}
                {{ form.gender }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

so for my form here it is:

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    year  = {}
    days  = {}
    month = {
        '': '---------',
        'Jan': 'January', 'Feb': 'February', 'Mar': 'March',
        'Apr': 'April', 'May': 'May', 'Jun': 'June', 'Jul': 'July',
        'Aug': 'August', 'Sep': 'September', 'Oct': 'October',
        'Nov': 'November', 'Dec': 'December'
    }
    gender = {
        'Male': 'Male', 'Female': 'Female',
        'Not Specify': 'Not Specify'
    }

    year[''] = '---------'
    days[''] = '---------'

    from datetime import datetime

    for i in range((int(datetime.now().strftime('%Y'))), (1920 - 1), -1):
        year[i] = i

    for i in range(1, (31 + 1)):
        if i < 10:
            days[f'0{i}'] = f'0{i}'
        else:
            days[i] = i

    password = forms.CharField(label = 'Password', widget = forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_password',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Password'
        }
    ), required = True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label = 'Email', widget = forms.EmailInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_email',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Email',
            'autocomplete': 'off'
        }
    ), required = True)
    firstname = forms.CharField(label = 'Firstname', widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_firstname',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Firstname',
            'autocomplete': 'off'
        }
    ), required = True)
    lastname = forms.CharField(label = 'Lastname', widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_lastname',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Lastname',
            'autocomplete': 'off'
        }
    ), required = True)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Gender', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_gender',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(gender.items()), required = False)
    birthdate_year = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Year', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_birthyear',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(year.items()), required = True)
    birthdate_day = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Day', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_day',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(days.items()), required = True)
    birthdate_month = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Month', widget = forms.Select(
        attrs = {
            'id': 'id_signup_month',
            'class': 'form-control',
        }
    ), choices = list(month.items()), required = True)

    class Meta:
        model   = UserInfoModel
        fields  = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'gender', 'birthdate_year', 'birthdate_month', 'birthdate_day']
```

I just dont want to use/show the `email` and `password` when the user will update there personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UserInfoForm` you can specify with fields what fields you want. For example:

```
class UserInfoForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfoModel
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'birthdate', 'gender')
```

It will thus not define other fields. Furthermore if a user creates a malicious POST request with extra key-value pairs, then the form will *not* update the ones not listed in the form.

Comment: my form has already a class meta, and define those fields already but it keeps showing the other fields when I do the `{{ form.as_p }}` on the template view. ok to make it clear, this `UserInfoForm` have the field of username and password, and I dont want them to be include when user want to update their profile information so that is why i'm looking for a solution on how to not include that fields on the template and just update the necessary field.

Comment: @KimNicoleSabordo: but by not rendering it on the template, it will not work, since then the POST request will not pass this data to the form, and hence the form will be invalid. The point is that the form needs to know what fields are present, and which are *not* present. If you use this form somewhere else, you just can make an extra `UserInfoForm` (for example `UpdateUserInfoForm`, and thus specify different fields).

Comment: so it means that I can not re-use the form already? instead i will make another one for the update?

Comment: @KimNicoleSabordo: well unless these fields are not-required, no. But even if that is the case, it is better to make separate ones, to make sure that if you later change your mind, the form is not somehow updated and no longer works.

Comment: well, if that is the solution. i tried that before and it works i just dont want to be redundant. but if there is no other way well then stick on that solution. hey can you update your post answer to the right one, so that i could mark it as the answer. thanks.

Comment: @KimNicoleSabordo: furthermore you can use inheritance. You can for example make an `UpdateUserInfoForm`, that already defines the `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. fields, and then subclass this to a `UserInfoForm`, that then adds some extra fields.

Comment: yes i agree, but in my `UserInfoForm` i have some extra fields there, so i dont want it to extend it the class, but good suggestion . thanks.